# Can I lay two Highcharts series side-by-side?

Tags: highcharts

Looking at this example: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume

Is there a way that I can lay these two series side-by-side rather than stacked on top?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried that is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `axis.width` and `axis.left`. You will not find them in axis official [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis), so you may encounter some issues with it, e.g. problem with a tooltip - [issue on github](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/2062).

The basic config for using two x axis next to each other:

```
xAxis: [{
  width: 200,
  left: 50
}, {
  width: 200,
  left: 300,
  linkedTo: 0,
  offset: 0
}],
```

Workaround for a tooltip position (shared tooltip does not seem to work correctly)

```
tooltip: {
  shared: false,
  shape: 'rect',
  positioner: function(w, h, p) {
    return {
      x: p.plotX + this.chart.hoverSeries.xAxis.left - w / 2,
      y: p.plotY
    }
  }
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/fqc5np5g/

[image: two x axis stockchart]